# Timepicker dialog on Android Wear - Material timepicker is too big?

Tags: android, wear-os

I am trying to develop for Android Wear and I need to use a time picker dialog.

I tried using the Material dialog but it is too big to fit. I have tried resizing the time picker but the circular time selection on such a small screen is annoying for fat fingers. The user experience is poor.

I have reverted to holo time picker like this:
[image]

But it is very difficult to style this time picker. I will need to change the background, text font, size, colour, divider and buttons.

Have anyone come across something useful which may be able to solve this problem?

Comment: @Lorfeld could you tell me, what style exactly you are using on the screenshot above? Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?